# What actions are needed for a Angular 1.2 app to prevent XSS?

Tags: angularjs, xss

I recently came across this article:  http://blog.portswigger.net/2016/01/xss-without-html-client-side-template.html

I develop an enterprise app which has been using Angular 1.2 with some recent efforts to upgrade to 1.3 and beyond.

I would like to hear from others who has done specific changes for XSS prevention in a large app.

Answer (score 1):

He says:

> If you're using Angular, you need to either treat curly braces in user input as highly dangerous or avoid server-side reflection of user input entirely. Most other JavaScript frameworks have sidestepped this danger by not supporting expressions in arbitrary locations within HTML documents.

And I would keep this in mind: **avoid server-side reflection of user input**.